# Is Edge (significantly) better than Chrome for laptop battery life?

Tags: technology, computers

Microsoft recently released [the results of a benchmark](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2016/06/20/more-battery-with-edge/) of four different browsers with respect to battery life. Chrome comes out the worst, then Firefox, then Opera and then Edge, by quite a margin. Unsurprisingly, the news is being parroted by various

Has this kind of test been repeated by independent researchers? It seems like this kind of test is amazingly easy to fiddle by simply messing with the simulated browsing behaviour, and big companies have fiddled benchmarks before. It also doesn't help that this is precisely the perfect result for them, with their strongest competitor coming out worst.

<sub>Note: Opera [has already fired back](http://www.opera.com/blogs/desktop/2016/06/over-the-edge/) with a test of their own, but that's still not really independent.</sub>

Comment: It should be noted that for the majority of the testing period, Edge had crashed and was no longer using the processor. :b

Comment: The did not include Lynx in the tested browsers.

Comment: @SVilcans Theres a lot of browsers they didnt include, but those 4 are probably the most well known if not the most popular.

Comment: @JamesTrotter His point is that [lynx is a **text** browser](http://lynx.browser.org/) that allow you to view web pages *in the terminal*. which means to heavy graphic computations are done, and is like orders of magnitude more lightweight than *any* gui browser out there.

Comment: The two test are manipulated, and the lot of battery saving is due to ad blocking. Any default browser fare worse than any other with ad-blocking measure installed. We would need to have a test with default, non blocking browser, then all browser with ad blocking to see anything significant, and I doubt someone has 4 same laptop and 8+hr to lose :)

Comment: @DrakaSAN I have the laptops ... but you could do it with one laptop and 32 hours to lose.

Comment: @fredsbend: Well, as much as I d like to do that, I don't have the time nor a laptop I can put in a clean slate to ensure the quality of the test. Maybe in a few month, but I hope someone else will have put forth the effort before :)

Comment: Related: [Is Google Chrome killing my laptop battery?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/22630/37236)